# How to programmatically set mediaElement source

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, mediaelement

I have a MediaElement control and several videos whose **build action** is set to **content**, and **copy to output directory** set to **always**.

If I explicitly set the source in my xaml view like this:

```
<MediaElement Source="Media/StaticBrush.mp4" LoadedBehavior="Manual" Name="mePlayer" />
```

it works just fine, but now I need to programmically set the source.

Here is what I tried:

```
mePlayer.Source = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/MyAssemblyName;component/Media/StaticBrush.mp4");
```

and

```
mePlayer.Source = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Media/StaticBrush.mp4");
```

but no video appears.

Comment: I'm using MediaElement in the same way as you but after setting the source I'm calling Play() method on mePlayer.

Answer (score 0):

In WinUI3, it is using as below:

```
MediaPlayerElement mediaPlayerElement1 = new MediaPlayerElement();
mediaPlayerElement1.Source = MediaSource.CreateFromUri(new Uri("ms-appx:///Media/video1.mp4"));
mediaPlayerElement1.AutoPlay = true;
```